# How to set element width depending on number of elements?

Tags: html, css

I'm looking for a solution thanks to which I will be able to set element width based on number of elements in a row. On top of that, if number of elements in a row will reach "8", then next elements should be moved into another row. I'm using bootstrap 3.3.7.

```
.child-element {
    background:green;
    border:1px solid #fff;
}

/* one item */
.child-element:first-child:nth-last-child(1) {
    width: 100%;
}

/* two items */
.child-element:first-child:nth-last-child(2),
.child-element:first-child:nth-last-child(2) ~ .child-element {
    width: 50%;
}

/* three items */
.child-element:first-child:nth-last-child(3),
.child-element:first-child:nth-last-child(3) ~ .child-element {
    width: 33.3333%;
}

/* four items */
.child-element:first-child:nth-last-child(4),
.child-element:first-child:nth-last-child(4) ~ .child-element {
    width: 25%;
}

/* five items */
.child-element:first-child:nth-last-child(5),
.child-element:first-child:nth-last-child(5) ~ .child-element {
    width: 20%;
}

/* six items */
.child-element:first-child:nth-last-child(6),
.child-element:first-child:nth-last-child(6) ~ .child-element {
    width: 16.6666%;
}

/* seven items */
.child-element:first-child:nth-last-child(7),
.child-element:first-child:nth-last-child(7) ~ .child-element {
    width: 14.2857%;
}

/* eight items */
.child-element:first-child:nth-last-child(8),
.child-element:first-child:nth-last-child(8) ~ .child-element {
    width: 12.5%;
}
```

I've tried to implement following piece of code, but it simply doesn't work as demanded (its not working).

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row bg-red">
        <div class="col-lg-12"> 
                <div class="child-element">1</div>
                <div class="child-element">1</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

element width should be based on number of elements in a row. I have no idea how to add functionality of breaking 9th and more elements into second

Comment: you need javascript for that

Comment: it doesn't work because you are targeting previous element while `~` is for next element

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this: On parent, enable `flexbox`, then set `justify-content: space-between` and `flex-wrap: wrap`.
On each child, set `flex-grow: 1` to strech 100% of `width`, then set `min-width: calc(100%/8)` to set that it can't be less then 1/8 of `width`.
It will make all next elements to go next row.

```css
.parent {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item {
  flex-grow: 1;
  min-width: calc(100%/8);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
  <div class="item">7</div>
  <div class="item">8</div>
  <div class="item">9</div>
  <div class="item">10</div>
</div>
```

Example:

Comment: I think the space-between is useless since you set flex-grow to 1

Comment: Yes, it is. I put it without thinking straight. Thank you. Edited.